# How to default hide this javascript balloon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tooltip, balloon

I'm using a great Javascript popup balloon from here http://file.urin.take-uma.net/jquery.balloon.js-Demo.html .

The following code functions great, but the balloon is shown by default when the page loads. How can I make the balloon hidden on load and appear only when the image is clicked?:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#myballoon > img").showBalloon({
                position: "right",
                css: {}
            }).toggle(function() { $(this).hideBalloon(); }, function() { $(this).showBalloon(); });

        });
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: set the style of the balloon to `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your page:

```
#myballoon > img { display:none; }
```

that is assuming showBallon() acts on the image & not the parent (#myballoon) element

Answer (score 0):

By default, with Jquery.Just add on document ready this.

```
$("#myballoon > img").hide();
```

Comment: Hmm I couldn't get this method or that of @Precastic to work. I've added this in a new script after the code in the OP:                                                 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {jQuery("#myballoon > img").hide();
});
   </script> . Perhaps you can tell me what needs to be changed?

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {jQuery("#myballoon > img").hide(); /*then your balloon function*/}); </script>